# ngTable with requirejs - ngTableParams object is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, ngtable

Got a bit of a problem when using ngtable together with require js.
When i try to set the attributes of ngTableParams I get object is not a function
even though i copied the code from http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/3

My controller looks like this.

```
define(['./module', 'ngTable'], function (controllers) {
'use strict'; controllers.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'ngTableParams', function ($scope, $rootScope ngTableParams) {


 $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
           page: 1,            // show first page
           count: 10,          // count per page
           sorting: {
           name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
    }
    }, {
            total: data.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
            $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                           data;

            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(),       params.page() * params.count()));
         }
    }]);
});
```

If anyone got any ideas how to procees i would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post your trial to plnkr.co and let us see what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I changed

```
controllers.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'ngTableParams', function ($scope, $rootScope ngTableParams)]);
```

to the following

```
controllers.controller('myController', function ($scope, $rootScope ngTableParams)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a comma after `$rootScope` on line 2. It should read:

```
'use strict'; controllers.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'ngTableParams', function ($scope, $rootScope, ngTableParams) {
```